# Is it possible to map the dataset's batch size between layers?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Consider this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    Dense(10, batch_input_shape=(32, None, 100)),
    LSTM(1, stateful=True)
])
model.summary()

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (32, None, 10)            1010      
_________________________________________________________________
lstm  (LSTM)                 (32, 1)                   48        
=================================================================
Total params: 1,058
Trainable params: 1,058
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Regardless of whether such a model makes sense or not, the batch size on the first layer (the Dense layer) is set only because the LSTM has `stateful=True` and it needs the batch size. And the way to provide the batch size to it is through the first layer. That's why the Dense layer specifies the batch size.

I was wondering if there's a way to make this work:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    Dense(10, batch_input_shape=(None, 32, 100)),
    #Going from (None, 32, 10) to (32, None, 10)
    LSTM(1, stateful=True)
])
```

I know that this is possible before I start the model using the Dataset class methods (map, window, batch). But I was wondering if there's a way to do this between layers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you can do that using a Lambda layer:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    Dense(10, batch_input_shape=(None, 32, 100)),
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.reshape(x, (32, -1, 10))),
    LSTM(1, stateful=True)
])
model.summary()

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 32, 10)            1010      
_________________________________________________________________
lambda (Lambda)              (32, None, 10)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm   (LSTM)                (32, 1)                   48        
=================================================================
Total params: 1,058
Trainable params: 1,058
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Who knew!?

Comment: Did you try `tf.keras.layers.Reshape(32, -1, 10)`?

Comment: Nope. That layer type cannot change the batch size dimension.